# Can I export my Rock Band 3 avatars?

Tags: xbox-360, rock-band-3

I have some nice avatars that I laboured over in the character editor, and I've grown rather attached to them. Is there any way at all to export them? I'd like to be able to bring my avatars with me when playing Rock Band at my friend's place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your profile and save game data to a USB flash drive and then bring the flash drive to your friend's house. When you arrive, plug in the flash drive and you should have access to your profile and any save games you have saved to the drive.

The advantage to this over simply saving the save game to the cloud storage is that it is much easier to login to a profile from the flash drive than to download the profile to the other system, and has the additional advantage that you don't leave you profile behind where someone might do something with it that you don't want to.

Or, split the difference and put your profile on the flash drive and the save game in the cloud.

Comment: What about the other way of splitting the difference, putting the save game on a drive and downloading my profile?

Comment: Yeah, you could. However if you're going to be dragging a flash drive around anyway, why not put the thing that you really don't want someone else messing with on the flash drive as well?

Comment: It's entirely possible that the other person is an extremely close, good friend who I go back years with. :) For those circumstances, it's good to know the drive saves don't need to be tied to a profile on the drive or something odd like that.

Comment: Tested this last weekend, and it worked a charm!

Answer (score 1):

If you have Gold you *may* be able to save your game to the cloud and then log into your XBL account at your friend's place. If you can save it to the cloud you will get your avatars.

Comment: Can the Xbox save any game data to the cloud, or does the game have to support cloud storage? My account is Silver, but it may be worth paying for Gold if I knew this worked.

Comment: Every game I have can save to the cloud,  I actually never do this becaus sometimes the internetsignal is to bad to use it but I think its for every game. Gold is also useful for online play and discount on the XBL marktplace. You could also get Gold for just one month to try it. (I think theres als one for just 48 hours)

Comment: I've run across one or two games that don't support cloud storage. But the _vast_ majority do.

Comment: Since moving the data via a USB stick works, I can only assume that moving it via Cloud will also work, so +1 for you!